# Google ChartEditor to open up on the "Customize" tab

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I have a very simple script that opens up the Google ChartEditor for a chart:

```
 function loadEditorG1() {
    chartEditorG1 = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditorG1, 'ok', redrawChartG1);
    chartEditorG1.openDialog(wrapperG1, {});   
}

function redrawChartG1(){   
  wrapperG1 = chartEditorG1.getChartWrapper();  
  wrapperG1.draw();
}
```

How can I make the loadEditorG1() function open up the editor on the "Customize" tab? By default Google ChartEditor opens up on the "Start" tab.

Comment: really? NOBODY has anything to say about this? Are you guys trying to tell me that I have stumbled onto something that "cannot be done" ?

Comment: i tried by finding the _"Customize" tab_ in the DOM and triggering a click event, but nothing happens...

Comment: thank you for trying @WhiteHat
I appreciate that.